# Quartz Error: No Suitable driver

Tags: quartz-scheduler

I have used Quartz jobs in my web application. Everything was working fine when I used Quartz 1.6.5 with Teradata database version 13.10.

I faced frequent deadlock issues in the quartz older version. So, I upgraded my version to Quartz2.2.1. Everything was working fine when I used Quartz 2.2.1 with Teradata database version 13.10.

Later we faced a weird charset issue in Teradata 13.10, so we upgraded to Teradata 14.0.

Now, we faced a weird problem, when we used Quartz 2.2.1 with Teradata database version 14.0

We got the following exception,

```
INFO >2014-03-20 10:35:34,541 com.mchange.v2.log.MLog[main]: MLog clients using log4j logging.
INFO >2014-03-20 10:35:35,007 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.C3P0Registry[main]: Initializing c3p0-0.9.1 [built 16-January-2007 14:46:42; debug? true; trace: 10]
INFO >2014-03-20 10:35:35,504 com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource[main]: Initializing c3p0 pool... com.mchange.v2.c3p0.ComboPooledDataSource [ acquireIncrement -> 3, acquireRetryAttempts -> 30, acquireRetryDelay -> 1000, autoCommitOnClose -> false, automaticTestTable -> null, breakAfterAcquireFailure -> false, checkoutTimeout -> 0, connectionCustomizerClassName -> null, connectionTesterClassName -> com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.DefaultConnectionTester, dataSourceName -> 30b5x8901q4ns4b1b241po|1b7bf86, debugUnreturnedConnectionStackTraces -> false, description -> null, driverClass -> com.objectriver.jdbc.driver.L2PDriver, factoryClassLocation -> null, forceIgnoreUnresolvedTransactions -> false, identityToken -> 30b5x8901q4ns4b1b241po|1b7bf86, idleConnectionTestPeriod -> 0, initialPoolSize -> 3, jdbcUrl -> jdbc:teradata://10.219.82.10/database=T01DGF0_Q,CHARSET=UTF8,TMODE=TERA, lastAcquisitionFailureDefaultUser -> null, maxAdministrativeTaskTime -> 0, maxConnectionAge -> 0, maxIdleTime -> 0, maxIdleTimeExcessConnections -> 0, maxPoolSize -> 10, maxStatements -> 0, maxStatementsPerConnection -> 120, minPoolSize -> 1, numHelperThreads -> 3, numThreadsAwaitingCheckoutDefaultUser -> 0, preferredTestQuery -> null, properties -> {user=******, password=******}, propertyCycle -> 0, testConnectionOnCheckin -> false, testConnectionOnCheckout -> false, unreturnedConnectionTimeout -> 0, usesTraditionalReflectiveProxies -> false ]
WARN >2014-03-20 10:36:04,519 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#0]: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@18837f1 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
INFO >2014-03-20 10:36:05,903 com.ssc.faw.common.LogManager[GenCache]: GenCache.Worker(1) created
WARN >2014-03-20 10:36:06,657 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#2]: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@150b45a -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
WARN >2014-03-20 10:36:06,657 com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool[com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread-#1]: com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask@170a650 -- Acquisition Attempt Failed!!! Clearing pending acquires. While trying to acquire a needed new resource, we failed to succeed more than the maximum number of allowed acquisition attempts (30). Last acquisition attempt exception:
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver
at java.sql.DriverManager.getDriver(DriverManager.java:264)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.driver(DriverManagerDataSource.java:224)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.DriverManagerDataSource.getConnection(DriverManagerDataSource.java:135)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:182)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.getPooledConnection(WrapperConnectionPoolDataSource.java:171)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool$1PooledConnectionResourcePoolManager.acquireResource(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:137)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.doAcquire(BasicResourcePool.java:1014)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool.access$800(BasicResourcePool.java:32)
at com.mchange.v2.resourcepool.BasicResourcePool$AcquireTask.run(BasicResourcePool.java:1810)
at com.mchange.v2.async.ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner$PoolThread.run(ThreadPoolAsynchronousRunner.java:547)
```

Please find the following quartz properties and jobs xml,

quartz.properties

```
#==============================================================
# Registry Scheduler Properties
#==============================================================
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName=Service_Dgf_Quartz_Scheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.makeSchedulerThreadDaemon = true

#============================================================================
# Cluster Configuration
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered = true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.selectWithLockSQL=LOCKING ROW FOR WRITE SELECT * FROM {0}LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME = ?
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO

#==============================================================
# Configure ThreadPool
#==============================================================
org.quartz.threadPool.class=org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount=10
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority=5

#==============================================================
# Configure JobStore
#==============================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreTX
org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass = com.ssc.mfw.server.quartz.TeradataDelegate

#========================================================================================
# Configure JobInitializer Plugin
#========================================================================================
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.wrapInUserTransaction = false
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.class = org.quartz.plugins.xml.XMLSchedulingDataProcessorPlugin
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.scanInterval = 0
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.fileNames=quartz/service_dgf_jobs.xml
org.quartz.plugin.jobInitializer.failOnFileNotFound = true

#============================================================================
# Configure Plugins
#============================================================================
org.quartz.plugin.triggHistory.class = org.quartz.plugins.history.LoggingJobHistoryPlugin

#============================================================================
# Configure JobStore Additional Code
#============================================================================
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties = false
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource = QuartzDS
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix = QRTZ_

org.quartz.dataSource.QuartzDS.connectionProvider.class=com.ssc.mfw.server.util.TeradataConnectionProvider
```

**quartz_jobs.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<job-scheduling-data
xmlns="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/JobSchedulingData http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/xml/job_scheduling_data_1_8.xsd"
version="1.8">

<schedule>
<job>
<name>simpleJob</name>
<group>SimpleGroup</group>
<description>Mart Creation Job</description>
<job-class>com.ssc.mfw.server.job.VirtualMartCreationJob</job-class>
</job>
<trigger>
<!-- ServiceNotification will be fired every 5 minutes -->
<cron>
<name>simpleJobTrigger</name>
<job-name>simpleJob</job-name>
<job-group>SimpleGroup</job-group>
<cron-expression>0 0/5 * * * ?</cron-expression>
</cron>
</trigger>
</schedule>

<schedule>
<job>
<name>dashboardJob</name>
<group>dashboardGroup</group>
<description>Dashboard Job</description>
<job-class>com.ssc.mfw.server.job.DashBoardJob</job-class>
</job>
<trigger>
<!-- ServiceNotification will be fired every 12 hours -->
<cron>
<name>dashboardJobTrigger</name>
<job-name>dashboardJob</job-name>
<job-group>dashboardGroup</job-group>
<cron-expression>0 0 0/12 * * ?</cron-expression>
</cron>
</trigger>
</schedule>

<schedule>
<job>
<name>updateAsAtTmsJob</name>
<group>updateAsAtTmsGroup</group>
<description>Update DB Key Job</description>
<job-class>com.ssc.mfw.server.job.UpdateAsAtTmsJob</job-class>
</job>
<trigger>
<!-- ServiceNotification will be fired every 4 hours -->
<cron>
<name>updateAsAtTmsJobTrigger</name>
<job-name>updateAsAtTmsJob</job-name>
<job-group>updateAsAtTmsGroup</job-group>
<cron-expression>0 0 0/4 * * ?</cron-expression>
</cron>
</trigger>
</schedule>
</job-scheduling-data>
```

We are facing the above said only when quartz database tables are empty. If the quartz tables contains the job details, jobs are running fine.

Can any one advice what is causing the issue? Am I doing anything wrong here.

Regards,
Suresh.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is pretty simple: JDBC cannot resolve the URL you have provided of the database to an appropriate Driver class. You can fix this very easily in several different ways, but unfortunately it's hard to give specific advice, because all of your JDBC configuration is hidden behind...

```
org.quartz.dataSource.QuartzDS.connectionProvider.class=com.ssc.mfw.server.util.TeradataConnectionProvider
```

In all likelihood, that class overides `org.quartz.utils.PoolingConnectionProvider`, and when it does so, it provides String `dbDriver` as the first argument to its superconstructor. (That string may be hardcoded, or externally configured somehow.) You need to update that String to the JDBC driver appropriate to your new version of Teradata. You will also need to ensure that the JDBC url you are using, probably, the second argument to the superconstructor of TeradataConnectionProvider, is a URL to your new database that is consistent with the `dbDriver` class you have surprised. Check the Teradata 14 JDBC documentation docs for the driver name and compatible JDBC url format.

(If your TeradataConnectionProvider implementation supplies its superconstructor with a Properties object, make sure that the key "driver" is bound to the JDBC driver class name and that the String URL is bound the the appropriate JDBC URL.)

(If you want more specific help, include the source to TeradataConnectionProvider.)

(Alternatively and more transparently, configure your DataSource directly using the config properties defined [here](http://quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/configuration/ConfigDataSources).)

Answer (score 0):

We are using another third party jar to create connections. That third party jar accepts URL in a specific format. We were sending the URL in wrong format. Now, we have fixed the issue and got it working. @Steve: Thanks for your time and support.